# separate code from template pages in wordpress(separate view and the code)

Tags: wordpress, architecture, wordpress-theming

This is for the wordpress developer out there whos been doing this for a long time, what i want is a suggestion on how to structure my code, what i want is a "separation of concern". Here is my set up right now, I have a page template that is a form, and i want a separate file to abstact the code from the template page. What im after is a maintainable code base.

Can you guys give me an suggestion, on how would you structure your code base, in a maintainable way. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### You're looking for `get_template_part()`

> Loads a template part into a template.
> Provides a simple mechanism for child themes to overload reusable sections of code in the theme.

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

| [Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/#parameters) | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `$slug` | (string) (Required) The slug name for the generic template. |
| `$name` | (string) (Optional) The name of the specialised template. Default value: null |

In your case we could place your form in a template part, eg: `custom-page-form.php` then on the front end call it via `<?php get_template_part( 'custom-page-form.php' ); ?>`.

Comment: how do i do "separation of concern" on that template part, i dont want to put the code on the template file, i want to separate the markup and the code

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for kinda MVC, I would suggest you to use [Timber](https://github.com/timber/timber). It provides [twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) template engine to handle your views, while logic behind it (models, controllers, config, etc) can be organized anywhere (but the endpoint must be **functions.php**).

Also, **index.php** must be present in theme, so it could be a start point for rendering your views. In fact, it could be any general WordPress template, but I prefer to keep only index.php.

Comment: Is there like an approach, where i dont need to use extra technologies anymore, maybe a way that i can just adjust, the way i write my code.